# HAML converts HTML to Ascii characters

Tags: ruby, haml

I have an issue with HAML, when i want to convert the HAML file to HTML.

More exactly i have this...

```
%img{:src='{% static "ex.jpg" %}'}
```

After converting to HTML, will show up like this

```
<img src='{% static &#34;ex.jpg&#34; %}'/>
```

What I want is:

```
<img src='{% static "ex.jpg" %}'/>
```

Now, i know that is not the way you would write the *%img* tag, but i would need the "ex.jpg" to be displayed as it is in the rendered HTML file, and not with ASCII Characters.

How can i convert the HAML file to HTML, without the ascii characters?

Thanks

Comment: "And i need it like this `<img src='"ex.jpg"'/>`" — But that is not valid HTML, so why would you need it like that?

Comment: because i want to use some django tags inside of it. Like this: %img{:src='{% static "ex.jpg" %}', so when the HTML will be rendered, i will have the static tag in it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas. One is to switch quotes:

```
%img{:src="{% static 'ex.jpg' %}"}
```

Another is to just put in the text as you want it:

```
<img src='{% static "ex.jpg" %}'/>
```

Skipping the HAML part. You can always revert to regular HTML in HAML.

Double quotes are special in HTML and HAML will go out of its way to properly escape them so it produces a valid HTML document. What you're trying to produce isn't valid until Django has done its thing.

Comment: if i put i like the first suggestion, it will still not render them like 'ex.jpg', instead it will add the ascii code. I tried :(. The second ideea is much more interesting. :)

Comment: If it's not legit HTML you may need to side-step HAML, but the good news is HAML allows you to write in *whatever* so you can do that.